# Convert all data frame's columns to multiple vectors in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a data frame of 60 columns and >3K rows; such as:

```
a1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
.
.
a60 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
passem = data.frame(a1, a2, ..., a60)
```

I want to convert the **WHOLE** data frame's columns to multiple vectors (so 60 columns will give exactly 60 vectors, each named by its corresponding column name).

I can do so manually for each column, but this is difficult and time-consuming; for example:

```
a1vector <- as.vector(passem['a1'])
a2vector <- as.vector(passem['a2'])
.
.
a60vector <- as.vector(passem['a60'])
```

Can this job be done with a single or limited line of commands or functions in R?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign()` in a loop:

```
for (col in names(passem)) {
  assign(col, passem[[col]])
}

a1
# 1 2 3 4 5

a60
# 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `list2env`.

```
list2env(passem, .GlobalEnv)
```